# How to run Jupyter notebook as administrator on Mac?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

To listen to keyboard inputs on python, it is nessecary for me to run the program as an administrator. How can I do this on a Mac?

Comment: have you tried to install jupyter and run it? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I have used jupyter for a long time. It is when I tried to detect key presses with python library keyboard where executing the code as an administrator is nessecary.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the specific library, and what exactly are you trying to do with it? Are you trying to use the library within Jupyter?